# pandas assign value to more than one columns based on a condition using more than 20 columns

Tags: python, pandas

Below is a SAS code which i am trying to convert to python. I could think of doing this using list `comprehension`. or by using a big nested condition using `np.where`. But i think there is a more efficient way to achieve the output.

The pandas data frame has columns `day1, day2 ... day30` and `dw1, dw2... dw30`. The condition is to look for any column(say `day(x)` greater than 0 in `day2 to day30` and assign `'Y'` to flag column. and assign `'Y'` to dwflag if `dw(x-1)` is not  0.

Data

```
day1 day2 day3 day4  dw1 dw2 dw3 dw4
1    1    0    1      0  0   0   0
1    0    1    1      1  0   0   0
1    1    1    0      0  0   0   0
1    1    1    0      0  0   1   0
1    1    1    1      0  0   0   0
```

Expected output

```
day1 day2 day3 day4  dw1 dw2 dw3 dw4  dflag  dwflag
1    1    0    1      0  0   0   0     Y      N
1    0    1    1      1  0   0   0     Y      Y
1    1    1    0      0  0   0   0     Y      N
1    1    1    0      0  0   1   0     Y      Y
1    1    1    1      0  0   0   0     N      N
```

SAS Code

```
   dflag= 'N';
   DO I = 2 TO 30  WHILE(dflag='N');
      IF day(I) = 0 THEN    
        DO;
           dflag='Y';
           IF dw(I-1) NE 0 THEN 
              dwflag = 'Y';
        END;
   END;
   IF dwflag NE 'Y' THEN dwflag='N';
```

Comment: To be clear, you want to apply the same logic repeatedly to a bunch of rows of an array (or DataFrame)... and you don't want any kind of loop to occur? Or you just want the looping to be done internally by Numpy (or Pandas)? Did you try to write, for example, the `np.where` version? If so, what did you find unsatisfactory about it?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes. thats correct. np.where gets too long as it has to go over 29 columns. So im looking for a way to identify the first `day` column with zero from 30 `day` columns.

Comment: To be clear: you want to look for rows where every cell value is zero?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel No. i want to find the `first` cell with zero value in it. Then on finding the first occurance , it stops checking for rest of the `cells` and moves to next `row`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Modified to add a bit more explanation. Hope it helps :)

Comment: I mean, what is the significance of finding that cell? what will you do with that information? And what will you do if you don't find such a cell, that is different from what you do when you do find one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230218/discussion-between-karl-knechtel-and-sjd).

Comment: Your current SAS code does not really seem to be doing what you say you want.  It is just setting a yes/no flag not locating which variable caused the flag to become set.

Comment: @Tom its setting yes/no flag to 2 variables based on a pair of columns day and dw

Comment: Please see the example dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i could finally come up with.

```
day_cols = [f'day{i}' for i in range(2,31)]

df['days_min_value'] = df[day_cols].min(axis=1)
df['dw_colname'] = df[day_cols].idxmin(axis=1).str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)-1
df['dw_colname'] = 'dw'+df['dw_colname'].astype(str)

df['dflag'] = np.where(df['days_min_value'] == 0, 'Y', 'N')
df['dwflag'] = np.where( (df['dflag'] == 'Y') & (df[df['dw_colname']] != 0), 'Y', 'N')
df.drop(['days_min_value', 'dw_colname'], inplace=True)
```